# How can i separate fields in JSP from text file?

Tags: jsp, text, field

I have a perl script which is search for the latest modified files in a specified folders. When the search end this script put the data in a text file into structure:

```
   [COMP] = folder1
   [DATE] = 2015.06.01 08:12
   [COMP] = folder1
   [DATE] = 2015.06.01 05:27
   [COMP] = folder1
   [DATE] = 2015.05.31 11:44:44
```

...etc

For the display i have to use jsp, because the server running Tomcat.

Here's my index.jsp:

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*, java.util.*" %>

<%
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
String file = (context.getRealPath("/list.txt"));
String s, list = new String();

try {
        DataInputStream in =
        new DataInputStream(
        new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(file)));
                while((s = in.readLine())!= null) {
                        list += s + "\n";
                }
        in.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
%>
<pre>
<%=list%>
</pre>
```

Now, the "list" variable contain the COMP and DATE fields data.

So, my question is, how can i separate the fields (COPM, DATE) in JSP from text file?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Use an index to keep track of line numbers. If it is even, add to a COMP list, otherwise add to a DATE list.

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.*, java.util.*" %>

<%
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
String file = (context.getRealPath("/list.txt"));
String s = new String();
List<String> compList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0;

try {
    DataInputStream in =
    new DataInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(file)));
            while((s = in.readLine())!= null) {
                  if(i % 2 = 0) {
                     compList.add(s);
                  } else {
                     dateList.add(s);
                  }  
                  i++;
            }     
    in.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
%>
<pre>
<%=compList%>
<%=dateList%>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are on different lines on the text file. You just have to read them separately :

```
    DataInputStream in =
    new DataInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(file)));
    String comp, sdate;
    while(True) {
        comp = in.readLine(),
        if (comp == null) { break;}
        sdate= in.readLine(),
        if (sdate== null) { break;}
        // you have comp and sdate : use them and put result in list
      }
    in.close();
```

You can use the `java.util.regex` package to parse each individual line. But if you really want to have a nice presentation, you'd better use a servlet to parse to input text file, put the elements as a List in a request attribute, forward to the jsp file and use the JSP to format the result **Java code is JSP is hard to test and debug** do not put intelligence in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! Here's my solution (not the whole, wokring code):

```
my %hash = ();

loop start // folder read etc
some if statement

 if ($before_on_week le $d)
  {
   $row = $row . " <td>$d</td>\n";
  }
 else
  {
   $row = $row . " <td><b><font color=red>$d</font></b></td>\n";
  }

   $row = $row . " <td>/var/www/$path</td>\n";
   $row = $row . "</tr>\n";
   #print FILE $row;
   $hash{"$d $path"} = $row;

loop end

foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    my $row = $hash{$key};
    print FILE $row;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The data in file is stored as key & value pairs.
What you have to do in JSP is, instead reading file as steam, you need to read as properties file using java.util.Properties class.

The code like below should work.

```
try{
  Properties props = new Properties();   
  props.load(file);
  String value1 = props.get("[COMP]");
  String value2 = props.get("[DATE]");
}
```

Try it out.

Comment: It won't work. You will get only the last two lines. Try it out.